# Django allauth signup form empty

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I'm trying allauth for the first time and having difficulty signing up for the first time. I am using the Facebook support and I connect to Facebook successfully, logging in and get to /accounts/social/signup:

where my Facebook name and email address are pre-filled, but the button doesn't work, quite possibly because the form action is empty. I checked the allauth package template, and it seems designed this way. I'm not sure what's going on, but it's not working for me. Please help!

Excerpt from rendered page `http://localhost:8000/accounts/social/signup/`

```
<p>{% blocktrans with provider_name=account.get_provider.name site_name=site.name %}You are 
about to use your {{provider_name}} account to login to 
{{site_name}}. As a final step, please complete the following form:{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>
```

excerpt from `/virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/templates/socialaccount/signup.html`

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
{% if redirect_field_value %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
{% endif %}
<button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action was left out in code and has now been [changed on github](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/commit/5aec19d709ee5303edc2fd2d97c8e95662229b94), although apparently not in the pip package directory, thus I installed the error.